# How to find top n% of records in a dataframe and change it to 1, otherwise 0

Tags: r, binary, percentage

I have a data frame like：

```
v1 v2 v2 v4 v5 v6 v7 v8
1  10 8  8  50 19 41 20
11 21 87 67 23 49 14 0
88 24 55 67 24 67 56 90
```

what I want is that if the value in the top 5% or 10% of all values, then change to 1;
if not, replace by 0.
the structure is like below :(it is not a true result, just show the structure I want to get)

```
0  0 0  0  1 0 0 1
0  0 1  0  0 0 0 1
0  1 0  0  1 0 0 1
```

are there any fast ways?  My data is about 60*639

Comment: Should not the first row have 3 ones instead of 2? How do you obtain the first row?

Comment: Sorry, this not the true result, I just want to show the structure what I want to get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R:

```r
1*(as.matrix(df) > quantile(unlist(df), 0.95))
#>      v1 v2 v2.1 v4 v5 v6 v7 v8
#> [1,]  0  0    0  0  0  0  0  0
#> [2,]  0  0    0  0  0  0  0  0
#> [3,]  1  0    0  0  0  0  0  1
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
df
# A tibble: 3 x 8
     v1    v2  v2_1    v4    v5    v6    v7    v8
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    10     8     8    50    19    41    20
2    11    21    87    67    23    49    14     0
3    88    24    55    67    24    67    56    90
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) +(x > quantile(sort(unlist(df)), 0.95, names = F)))
df
# A tibble: 3 x 8
     v1    v2  v2_1    v4    v5    v6    v7    v8
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
2     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
3     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
```

Comment: Comforting to get the same result...+1!

Comment: @AllanCameron, ha ha, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Another option can be pivot values to longer, then arrange by group. The lower top 5 will be allocated in the first 5 rows. Then you compute a binary variable and reshape to wide (Not sure if top 5 can be understood as the first 5 elements or other thing. Also I did the computing by in some sense "rows"):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Function
newdf <- df %>% mutate(id=row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-id) %>%
  arrange(id,value) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(Var=ifelse(row_number()<=5,0,1)) %>%
  select(-value) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from=name,values_from=Var) %>%
  ungroup() %>% select(-id)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 8
     v1    v3    v4    v2    v6    v8    v7    v5
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1
2     0     1     1     0     1     0     0     0
3     1     0     0     0     1     1     0     0
```

Answer (score 0):

One `dplyr` option could be:

```
df %>%
 mutate(across(everything(), ~ as.numeric(. > quantile(unlist(df), 0.95))))

  v1 v2 v2.1 v4 v5 v6 v7 v8
1  0  0    0  0  0  0  0  0
2  0  0    0  0  0  0  0  0
3  1  0    0  0  0  0  0  1
```